# A good way to delete all cache dirs of all CMSs under document root with Bash

Tags: find, rm, cache, wordpress, drupal

Say that under document root I have 3 apps; One is WordPress, second is Drupal, and third is Magento.

I wonder what's a good way to delete all cache directories of all CMSs under document root.

I could run a script with shell extensions for all (WP-CLI, Drush and Magento CLI), but what would be a good Bash-global way?

I thought of this to delete all cached files (`${drt}` = document root):

```
find ${drt}/*/cache/* -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code but I recommend creating a copy of your document root (if it's not alread backed up) and trying it there first before you put it into production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a slightly different `find` command, myself:

```
find "${drt}" -path "*/cache/*" -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

... so that `find` does the work of recursing down the directory tree; your example has the bash command-line expanding all of the `*`'s, giving `find` multiple starting paths. Also note that you don't need to `-r` recursively remove files (you're explicitly asking for files with `-type f`). This generalized version of the find command will also "catch" files that are in directories such as `${drt}/wordpress/subdir/cache/directory/filename`, where the cache directory is not one level underneath the document root. Whether that is something that you want or not depends on exactly where the cache directories are in your environment.

If you have GNU find (on e.g. Linux), you could simplify the removal with:

```
find "${drt}" -path "*/cache/*" -type f -delete
```